# error: (-215:Assertion failed) when i include a for loop inside the function

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

```py
def preprocess_image(image_path,resize=False):
        
    for path in image_path:

        img = cv2.imread(path)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = img / 255
        if resize:
            img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
        return img

#preprocess_image(image_paths)
image_paths = glob.glob("Plate_examples/*.jpg")
print("Found %i images..."%(len(image_paths)))

# Visualize data in subplot 
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
cols = 5
rows = 4
fig_list = []
for i in range(len(image_paths)):
    fig_list.append(fig.add_subplot(rows,cols,i+1))
    title = splitext(basename(image_paths[i]))[0]
    fig_list[-1].set_title(title)
    img = preprocess_image(image_paths[i],True)
    plt.axis(False)
    plt.imshow(img)

plt.tight_layout(True)
plt.show()
```

I want to loop through all the images and perform an operation on them when I remove the loop from the function everything works well, am trying to find the problem but just can't, can anyone help please.

Comment: What is the exact error message and at which command?

Comment: @fmw42 this is the error OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: @fmw42  i think i know the cause of the error but am just not able to find  a way around it

Comment: @fmw42 the problem is i try to iterate over a single str not a list, because when i run "preprocess_image(image_paths[1])"  it return only one image path which i cant iterate over, can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: `for img_path in img_paths:`

Answer (score 0):

`image_paths` is a list of file paths. Hence `image_paths[i]` is a single file path

> ```py
> img = preprocess_image(image_paths[i],True)
> ```

Because of the the argument `image_path`, of the function `preprocess_image`, is a string containing the file path. The `for`-loop `for path in image_path:` iterates through every character of the string.
If you want a function, that process all the images in a list, then you have to pass the list of files to the function. In the function you have to fill a list with the images. Finally return the image list from the function:

```py
def preprocess_images(image_path_list, resize=False):
        
    images = []
    for image_path in image_path_list:

        img = cv2.imread(image_path)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = img / 255
        if resize:
            img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
        images.append(img)

    return images
```

```py
images = preprocess_images(image_paths, True)

fig_list = []
for i, img in enumerate(images):
    
    fig_list.append(fig.add_subplot(rows,cols,i+1))
    title = splitext(basename(image_paths[i]))[0]
    fig_list[-1].set_title(title)
    plt.axis(False)
    plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Hi @rabbid76 this was my original code but i have to modify it to fit something else

Comment: @AgentCode I've changed the answer.